# "Неизвестная" — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно

В книжке (электронной) написано слитно:

> А на другой день на пороге комнаты, стуча высокими каблучками, появилась новая, ещё **неизвестная** Мите соседка.

Или правильно раздельно ("ещё", зависимое слово)?

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оставляем без изменения: А на другой день на пороге комнаты, стуча высокими каблучками, появилась новая, **ещё неизвестная** Мите соседка.

Наличие зависимых слов в общем случае не влияет на написание НЕ с прилагательными, **это касается и слова "ещё"**. Сравнить: ещё незнакомый ―  ещё чужой. Я им еще чужой человек.

**Поэтому задача решается по общему правилу для прилагательных, то есть возможно как слитное, так и раздельное написание НЕ.**

**1) Утверждение:** Еще недолго (мало времени) ждать весны.

Во Вселенной существуют **еще неизвестные** элементы. В лесах **ещё нередко** можно встретить диких животных. Когда мы ходили детьми в общественный сад, он стоял в нише, **еще неизвестный** нам как поэт, но уже Пушкин ― черный, чугунный, с баками, как я где-то сказал, выпуклыми, как виноград. [Ю. К. Олеша. Книга прощания (1930-1959)]

**2) Отрицательные конструкции:** Это еще не дорого, дом был еще не старый – выбор раздельной формы написания делается по смыслу, на слово с частицей НЕ обычно падает интонационное ударение, в том числе в обособленных оборотах; раздельное написание НЕ при усилении отрицания.

Защитником громоотвода на процессе выступал **никому еще не известный** адвокат Максимилиан Робеспьер. [В. П. Карцев (1970)] Сегодня утром защищал свой диплом заочник филфака Леонид Латынин, молодой поэт, **пока ещё не известный.** [Р. Г. Назиров. Дневник (1964)]

Answer (score 2):

Из ответа на аналогичный вопрос *справочной службы русского языка* на [**Грамоте.ру:**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=285221)

> Правильно: ***ранее неизвестный, пока неизвестный, еще
>   неизвестный***, но: ***никому не известный***... Наличие пояснительных
>   слов, как правило, не влияет на слитное написание ***не*** с
>   прилагательным. Исключение составляют только несколько случаев, один
>   из таких случаев – наличие в качестве пояснительных слов отрицательных
>   местоимений и наречий, начинающихся с ***ни.*** Их появление приводит
>   к замене слитного написания на раздельное.

Answer (score -2):

Раздельно, так как присутствует слово "ещё".